# Joining two tables in SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables. One called Employee and the other called Departments

These are the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Departmenr (
    department_code NCHAR(4),
    department_name NVARCHAR(15),
    city NVARCHAR(20),
    budget MONEY
)

CREATE TABLE Employee (
    employee_id NCHAR(6), 
    name NVARCHAR(20), 
    position NVARCHAR(20),
    salary MONEY, 
    dcode NCHAR(3),
)
```

I have to write a statement that lists the name of each employee and name of the department they work in, for all employees with who have a salary over £20,000. 
This means I have to join the Employee and Department tables to get an output.

I thought it might be something like this:

```
SELECT Emplyee.name, Department.department_name
FROM Employee
FULL OUTER JOIN Department 
ON Employee.salary > 20000;
```

but it has errors. 
How do I do this?

Comment: is dcode in employee a foreign key for department?

Comment: Your join doesn't appear to relate the two tables to each other. Your join needs to relate the value of a column from one table to the value of a column from the other.

Comment: to join two+ tables, you need to have fields in both that are related to each other, e.g. a "department_code" field in the employee table that's a foreign key to the departmentnr table.

Comment: If `Employee.dcode` relates to `Department.department_code`, then (a) why do they not have the same name? What do you gain by abbreviating one but not the other, except additional ambiguity for no reason? (b) why do they have different types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `dcode` is a foreign key for table department you can do:

```
SELECT e.NAME,d.department_name
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Department d ON e.dcode = d.department_code
WHERE e.salary > 20000;
```

Comment: you forgot the alias for department